# How to use an external HDD by different users?

Tags: external-hdd

I have a disk that is used by different users with the same desktop computer. When some of the users try to access the disk they are denied permission. 
how can I set up the disk for any person who mounts it?

After some thought, this is what I want to do. Have all users belong to each other's groups to everyone have access to each other's files and then give no access to everyone else:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving permission problems when using external EXT4 hard disk with multiple linux installs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12009/solving-permission-problems-when-using-external-ext4-hard-disk-with-multiple-lin)

Comment: I saw the other question and it's not a duplicate. My question is about multiple accounts in one PC

Comment: Try using ACLs ?

Comment: What filesystem is on the disk and how do you mount it?

Comment: Is an XFS partition and it's mounted automatically when I plug it in @honza-kasik